# No exported member MatCalendarCellClassFunction in Angular Material Datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to highlight specific dates on an Angular Material Datepicker view, following the guide as highlighted on the [material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview). The example there works fine, and so does the [Stackblitz one that is linked](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eqkopoqaglv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.ts).

I've tried importing it to my component as described in the docs with:

`import {MatCalendarCellClassFunction} from '@angular/material/datepicker';`

But I'm still running into the below error:

`@angular/material/datepicker"' has no exported member 'MatCalendarCellClassFunction'.`

Running version 10.0.3 and Material version 10.0.1. Should I be importing this from somewhere else?

Absolutely stumped on this one, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228429/4440629) helpful in sorting it out.

```
import { MatCalendarCellCssClasses } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import * as moment from 'moment';

selectedDateClass = (date: moment.Moment): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    const dateToHighlight: Date = new Date();

    // Highlight the date two days ago
    dateToHighlight.setDate(dateToHighlight.getDate() - 2);
    return (date.toDate().getDate() == dateToHighlight.getDate()) ? 'selected-date' : '';
  };
```

```
<mat-calendar [dateClass]="selectedDateClass"></mat-calendar>
```

```
.selected-date {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```