# Angular Material Datepicker: `dateClass` callback - Accessing Component's Properties and `this` Context

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, ngx-daterangepicker-material

I'm using Angular with Angular Material and Datepicker. I want to customize the CSS of specific dates in the Datepicker by applying a custom class. I'm utilizing the [`dateClass` parameter](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker) with an `@Input()` decorator to achieve this.

However, I'm facing issues with the implementation:

1. Accessing Component's Properties: In the `dateClassCallback` method, I need to access a property called `dateToCustom` which is an array of dates that should be styled differently. However, since this inside the `dateClassCallback` refers to the `NgxMatMonthView` rather than my component, I'm unable to access `dateToCustom`.
2. Closure and arrow functions are called properly but they are not adding any class to dates as expected.

I have referred to the official Angular Material documentation, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227497/angulare-material-datepicker-problem-with-dateclass) and [also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129826/angular-material-datepicker-dateclass), but I couldn't find a solution to these issues.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    @Component({
      // Component configuration
    })
    export class MyComponent {
      dateToCustom: Date[] = [
        new Date('2023-05-20'),
        new Date('2023-05-25'),
        // ...
      ];
    
      dateClassCallback = (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
        // Need access to dateToCustom, but unable to retrieve it here
        return this.dateToCustom.includes(date) ? 'myCustomClass' : '';
      };
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to overcome these issues and properly access the component properties within the dateClassCallback function. Thank you in advance for your help.